# How to send images or sounds to another iPhone/Android

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, audio, uiimage

I was wondering how games like Draw Something are sending the images to another iPhone/Android?
I want to be able to send a recorded sound/UIImage to another phone, how are they sent and received?
I'm relatively new to communication using iPhone.

I've googled and searched stackoverflow, but couldn't find anything.. maybe I'm not searching for the right query..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are sent via TCP/IP to a central server, or more likely, a group of servers. Those servers are responsible for storing the data and generating push notifications so the target device knows that new data is available. The target device downloads it from the central server(s), not directly from the other device.

On iOS, you can use the NSURLConnection class to push data to a server or read it back. The server is something you are also responsible for, although there are some third-party ones that you could use, like Urban Airship, to help with push notifications.

Comment: For images and sounds, using an NSData would be reasonable, yes. For other types of information (strings, numbers, booleans), a JSON string is usually better. If the images and sounds aren't too big, you can base64 encode the NSData into a string and put it inside a JSON string that is sent to the server.

Comment: I only understand about half of your answer, but I'll look into that.
Basically you say I need to convert it to NSData, send it using TCP to a server which in turn would relay it to other phones. correct?
How can it identify the required phone?

Comment: There's no "one way" to do it. Draw Something uses Facebook or a unique login id to identify devices. Push notifications use a unique device id called a push token. It's up to you to design a system that works for your app. In general you'll use the push token to send notifications to devices and a unique string of some sort to identify users or devices. I don't know of any pre-built 3rd party servers that do it all yet.

Comment: You might look at Open Feint - http://www.openfeint.com/ . I don't know much about it, but it might do what you want.